# Python: how to remove tuple from a large list based on similarity with other tuples

Tags: python, list, set, tuples, combinations

i have some issues with a python exercise. I have a large list of tuples of 10 elements, containing all combinations of 20 numbers.

```
import itertools

Comb = []

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
for i in itertools.combinations(data, 10):
        Comb.append(i)
```

I want to reduce the list removing tuples that have at least 7 elements in common with tuple of another list

```
L=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12)]
```

I've tried to resolve like this:

```
for x in Comb:
    for i, y in enumerate(Comb):
        for j in L:
            similarity = len(set(y).intersection(set(j)))
            if similarity > 7:
              del Comb[i]
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help?

Comment: do you experience any error or just a logical problem?

Comment: @phalanx it simply doesn't remove all the tuples that have more than 7 elements in common. Maybe there is a problem with index...

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a list (or set or dict) while you're looping over it in Python.

The simplest solution is to just create a new list.

```
import itertools
comb = list(itertools.combinations(range(10), 5))

# We'll remove any element with more than 3 even or odd numbers.
filters = ({0, 2, 4, 6, 8}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9})
threshold = 3

result = []
for element in comb:
    for filter_element in filters:
        if len(filter_element.intersection(element)) <= threshold:
            result.append(element)

# Make it smaller with a list comprehension
[elt for elt in comb
 if any(len(f.intersection(elt)) <= threshold for f in filters))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have test this and it works, print out some logs just to see what is going on

```
import itertools

Comb = []

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
for i in itertools.combinations(data, 10):Comb.append(i);
L=[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20),(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12)];
counter=0
print(len(Comb))
for x in Comb:
    for j in L:
        similarity = len(set(x).intersection(set(j)))
        if similarity > 7:
            print(str(similarity)+"\n"+str(set(x))+"\n"+str(set(j))+"\n\n")
            del Comb[counter]
    counter+=1;

print(len(Comb))
```